# Crontab Unix Shell Script EOF

Tags: shell, unix, cron

```
sqlplus -s u@t/t << EOF
drop table connection_backup;
CREATE TABLE connection_backup AS (SELECT * FROM connection);
drop table htbill_backup;
CREATE TABLE htbill_backup AS (SELECT * FROM htbill);
EXIT
EOF

Crontab -e File
*/1 * * * * sh ~/sql.sh | write $LOGNAME
```

due to the eof in first line crontab stops over their and does not execute further shell script

Comment: Can you explain this a little better? You have a file called `sql.sh` which contains the `sqlplus` lines up to `EOF`, and when you try to call that from within a cron file it doesn't seem to work? Did you try the full path to `sql.sh` instead of `~/`? Try subdividing and getting a simple shell script to work in the crontab, and then go from there.

Comment: i have also tried that when u write echo statements at begining and end it displays that but does not execute the sql statements

Answer (score 1):

**1. Get your shebang right**

Find where your favoured shell is, using this command:

```
whereis bash
```

or

```
whereis sh
```

Then, insert a new line at the top of your `sql.sh` script that says

```
#!<FULL PATH TO SHELL>
```

An example of the above would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

**2. Get your PATH right**

Find where `sqlplus` is installed on your system, with

```
whereis sqlplus
```

Add a new second line in your script that says

```
export PATH=${PATH}:<SQLPLUS DIRECTORY ONLY>
```

An example would be

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/bin         # Note the word `sqlplus` is omitted - we only specify the directory where it lives
```

**3. Make your script executable**

Make your `sql.sh` script executable with

```
chmod +x sql.sh
```

**4. Test your script outside cron**

Test your script with

```
./sql.sh
```

and make sure it works prior to continuing.

**5. Get the path to your script correct in cron**

Find your login directory with

```
cd
pwd
```

Change your crontab script so it says:

```
*/1 * * * * <LOGIN DIRECTORY>/sql.sh
```